# ActiveMQ JMS Durable Topic in a Network of Brokers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic, messaging

Say you have BrokerA and BrokerB connected to each other in the "Network of Brokers" Pattern. You have ClientZ connect to BrokerA and create a durable subscription to TopicT. That client disconnects for 15 mins from BrokerA, then reconnects to BrokerB.

Will all the messages it missed in those 15 mins be consumed even though it's now on BrokerB?

Will any messages remain on BrokerA?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very interesting question, but the concept of a "Network of Brokers" is not, as far as I know, part of the JMS API standard.  Therefore, there is no general answer to your question.

However, I see you have "activemq" in your question tags, and Apache ActiveMQ is a JMS provider implementation that *does* support "Network of Brokers".  So if you are using ActiveMQ, you may be able to find an answer in their documentation, which implies that to do what you want you should create a "virtual destination". See the following documentation:  http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-durable-subscribers-in-a-network-of-brokers.html